# how the client have access to web API without having the user security credentials?

Tags: security, authentication, networking, oauth

I am currently looking in depth to OAuth specification and I found it has 4 roles involved: server, resources owner, API server and user.

My question now how we the client (resource owner) can have access to an API without having the user's username and password?

Answer (score 0):

API server can be accessed with security token (bearer) inside Authorization header. Such token will be exchanged for username and password by authority server and will be valid for some time period (defined by the authority server). While this token is valid, it can be used to access API.

Some intro: http://www.slideshare.net/aaronpk/an-introduction-to-oauth2